# How to find tutors available time before assiging a task

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find out if any tutors are assigned sessions before their login time and if any sessions end after their logout time.

[image]

I am using one formula but it's not working correctly if time reaches midnight.

```
=IF(OR(AND(HOUR(G2)<HOUR(AE2), HOUR(K2)>HOUR(AE2)),  
  AND(HOUR(G2)=HOUR(AD2), MINUTE(G2)<MINUTE(AD2)), 
   AND(HOUR(K2)=HOUR(AE2), MINUTE(K2)>MINUTE(AE2))),
    "Not Available", "Available")
```

Comment: suggest sharing an example (e.g. screenshots) to demonstrate what information/data you have at the moment, and what is the desired outcome. You could mention what you have done so far, but more importantly, please explain what you are trying to achieve ultimately, whether or not using Excel formulas.

Comment: Hi! Terry, I have shared the screenshot. Please refer to the screenshot.

Comment: can you please also share a screenshot of the desired outcome? What would it look like if you were doing this manually?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula

```
=IF(OR(G26<AD26,K26>IF(AE26<AD26,AE26+1,AE26)),"NOT AVAIL","AVAIL")
```

[image]